# User input Calendar in C

Tags: c, calendar

I am making a calendar that prompts the user to enter the number of days in the month and the starting day. It displays

```
Enter number of days in month: 31
Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 7=Sat): 1
  1  2  3  4  5  6
  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
 21 22 23 24 25 26 27
 28 29 30 31
```

when it's supposed to display

```
Enter number of days in month: 31
Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 7=Sat): 1
      1  2  3  4  5  6  7
      8  9  10 11 12 13 14
     15 16 17 18 19 20 21
     22 23 24 25 26 27 28
     29 30 31
```

.

```
int main(void)
{
  int i, n, days, week;

  printf("Enter number of days in month: ");
  scanf("%d", &days);
  printf("Enter starting day of the week (1=Sun, 7=Sat): ");
  scanf("%d", &week);

  switch (week) {
    case 1: break;
    case 2: printf("   "); break;
    case 3: printf("      "); break;
    case 4: printf("         "); break;
    case 5: printf("            "); break;
    case 6: printf("               "); break;
    case 7: printf("                     "); break;
    default: printf("Error"); break;
    }
  
  for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
    if (week >= 8) {
      printf("\n");
      week = 0;
    }

    printf("%3d", i);

    week++;
  }
  

  return 0;
}
```

the week is supposed to represent spaces in the calendar

Comment: You need to add 3 more spaces to each string you print in the `switch/case` statements.

Comment: And instead of a case statement, you can just use a `for` loop that prints `week*3` spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution,
Instead of doing:

```
for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
    if (week >= 8) {
      printf("\n");
      week = 0;
    }
```

Do:

```
for (i = 1; i <= days; i++) {
    if (week > 7) {
      printf("\n");
      week = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).